# How to find out concurrency( in a second how many requests are made) in ATHENA for ELB logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, amazon-athena

I used this query to get **Total counts in a day** but I need **concurrency per second**, I got stuck here.

Please assist me further.

```
SELECT
 "count"("elb_status_code") "hits"
  
FROM
  alb_logs

WHERE ("date"("from_iso8601_timestamp"("time")) = "date"('2020-09-30'))
```

Comment: Are you looking for average number of queries in the day, divided by the number of seconds in the day? Or are you seeking -_actual_ concurrency throughout the day to see how many concurrent queries were running at any particular time?

Answer (score 1):

`date_trunc` should help you - see [here](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html)

```
SELECT 
date_trunc('second',"from_iso8601_timestamp"("time"))
,count("elb_status_code") "hits"
FROM alb_logs
WHERE ("date"("from_iso8601_timestamp"("time")) = "date"('2020-09-30'))
group by 1
order by 1
```